# Basic Quorum network design

Tags: blockchain, quorum

I have performed transaction using 7node example.
Need help to create a basic network in quorum.
From the 7node example i am finding it difficult to create a network.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your small customized quorum network of desired number of nodes. You can refer https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Quorum workspace on Slack where you can get advice and help.

You can join that by using the following link:
https://clh7rniov2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Express/